# Custom queries with CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, jpa, crud

I would like to custom my queries with CrudRepository :

This is my code:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

@Query("UPDATE customer c SET c.firstName = :firstName WHERE c.id = :id")
Integer setNewFirstNameForId(@Param("firstName") String firstName, @Param("id") long id);   
}



@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    protected Customer() {}

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }
```

But, when I compilate all of this, I have this an extract of the error :
"Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed;..."

Thank advance,

edit :

This is my error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Integer hello.CustomerRepository.setNewFirstNameForId(java.lang.String,long)!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:681)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
at hello.Application.main(Application.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Integer hello.CustomerRepository.setNewFirstNameForId(java.lang.String,long)!
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:80)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:54)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:65)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:48)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:115)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:160)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:69)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:304)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:161)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:220)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:206)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:84)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: customer is not mapped [UPDATE customer c SET c.firstName = :firstName WHERE c.id = :id]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:334)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:74)
... 24 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: customer is not mapped [UPDATE customer c SET c.firstName = :firstName WHERE c.id = :id]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1796)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
... 31 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: customer is not mapped
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:109)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:95)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:331)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3554)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3443)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.updateStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:363)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:255)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
... 39 more
```

Comment: Can you please accept an answer if someone solved your problem.

Answer (score 19):

Your first problem is in your JPQL:

```
@Query("UPDATE customer c SET c.firstName = :firstName WHERE c.id = :id")
```

type to

```
@Query("UPDATE Customer c SET c.firstName = :firstName WHERE c.id = :id")
```

That is because JPQL wants the query's table name to match your Entity Class name.

Another problem could be that you are missing the @Modifying annotation:

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE customer c SET c.firstName = :firstName WHERE c.id = :id")
  Integer setNewFirstNameForId(@Param("firstName") String firstName, @Param("id") long id);   
}
```

Every time you want modify by query, you should add the @Modifying anotation because Spring needs to know about it.

Comment: Sorry for that, next time my question will be in comment. I also edited my message

Comment: Thank !!, for update and delete I add "@Transactional" if not I am execution error.

Comment: I think JPQL is only for suicidal people. Go figure out this subtle difference of Customer against customer ....

Answer (score 2):

Also take in account that when you're creating custom queries you must use the Entity structure and not the final database structure.
For example you can have a composed private key. Then you Entity would have an attribute which would be the entity with the attributes that conform the private key. Example:

```
@Entity(name = "itemPrice")
public class ItemPriceEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ItemPriceComposedPK composedPK;

    // Rest of the fields
    ...

    // Getters and setters
    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class ItemPriceComposedPK implements Serializable {

   @Column
   private String id;

   @Column
   private int iteration;

   // Getters and setters
   ...
}
```

If you want to use the field *iteration*, then you must code something like: **i.composedPK.iteration**. Example:

```
@Modifying
@Query("select i from itemPrice i where i.composedPK.iteration = :it")
public List<ItemPriceEntity> searchByIteration(@Param("it") String it);
```

Of course CrudRepository offers a better way to make this query without using custom queries but, as an example, is ok.

Regards!

Answer (score -3):

In query use model/entity name it should work.